# Marshall array of structures

Tags: c#, .net, structure, marshalling

I've spent a lot of time to look for the solution but still don't find it out.

I have 2 classes:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Result
{
    public int Number;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string Name;
    public int Size;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CoverObject
{
    public int NumOfResults;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 4)]
    public Result[] Results;
}
```

My expectation that the command `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CoverObject))` will return 52, but not, it's just 20. Thus, all of marshall and unmarshall that I use later are not working.

Seeming it only counts the first member (Number) in Result class. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What do your unmanaged structs look like?

Comment: Do you mean struct written in C/C++ code?

Comment: @TuTran Yes, and also the pinvoke function declarations

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you! I found the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your classes to structs

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Result
{
    public int Number;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string Name;
    public int Size;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CoverObject
{
    public int NumOfResults;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 4)]
    public Result[] Results;
}
```

some where else:

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CoverObject)) // it will return 52
```

Comment: it works - but why is this change needed? is it also possible with classes?

Comment: No. classes are reference type but structures are value type. the way they are handled in memory is totally different