# How to properly convert array of structures to IntPtr in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, marshalling

I have structure in C++

```
struct {
      CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAGS Flags;
      NTSTATUS                                 CompletionStatus;
      LARGE_INTEGER                            PlaceholderTotalCount;
      CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO               *PlaceholderArray;
      DWORD                                    PlaceholderCount;
      DWORD                                    EntriesProcessed;
    } TransferPlaceholders;
```

And marshaling it to .Net:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct TRANSFERPLACEHOLDERS
            {
                /// <summary>Flags for transferring placeholders.</summary>
                public CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAGS Flags;

                /// <summary>The completion status of the operation.</summary>
                public NTStatus CompletionStatus;

                /// <summary>Total number of placeholders.</summary>
                public long PlaceholderTotalCount;

                /// <summary>An array of placeholders to be transferred.</summary>
                public IntPtr PlaceholderArray;

                /// <summary>The number of placeholders being transferred.</summary>
                public uint PlaceholderCount;

                /// <summary>The placeholder entries that have been processed.</summary>
                public uint EntriesProcessed;

            }
```

CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO marshalling:

```
[PInvokeData("cfapi.h", MSDNShortId = "2DC1FF5F-FBFD-45CA-8CD5-B2F586C22778")]
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO
        {
            /// <summary>The name of the child placeholder file or directory to be created.</summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            public string RelativeFileName;

            /// <summary>File system metadata to be created with the placeholder.</summary>
            public CF_FS_METADATA FsMetadata;

            /// <summary>
            /// A user mode buffer containing file information supplied by the sync provider. This is required for files (not for directories).
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr FileIdentity;

            /// <summary>Length, in bytes, of the <c>FileIdentity</c>.</summary>
            public uint FileIdentityLength;

            /// <summary>Flags for specifying placeholder creation behavior.</summary>
            public CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAGS Flags;

            /// <summary>The result of placeholder creation. On successful creation, the value is: STATUS_OK.</summary>
            public HRESULT Result;

            /// <summary>The final USN value after create actions are performed.</summary>
            public int CreateUsn;
        }
```

So I need to pass array of structures CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO to IntPtr PlaceholderArray.
I was trying to convert array of structures this way:

```
aPlaceholders.MarshalToPtr(Marshal.AllocHGlobal, out _);
```

But then I am receiving pointer of the first element of array only. So it works if array size is 1. Otherwise I receive Acess Violation 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
Also was trying to copy each element of array one by one using this function:

```
public void MarshalUnmananagedArray2Struct<T>(IntPtr unmanagedArray, int length, out T[] mangagedArray)
        {
            var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            mangagedArray = new T[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                IntPtr ins = new IntPtr(unmanagedArray.ToInt64() + i * size);
                mangagedArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(ins);
            }
        }
```

And having absolutley the same behavior, works only of array size is 1.
I guess I am doing something wrong when converting array to IntPtr. Will be glad to any help!

EDIT:
Source code for MarshalToPtr method

```
public static IntPtr MarshalToPtr<T> (this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<int, IntPtr> memAlloc, out int bytesAllocated, int prefixBytes = 0)
{
    if (!typeof (T).IsMarshalable ()) throw new ArgumentException (@"Structure layout is not sequential or explicit.");
    
    bytesAllocated = prefixBytes;
    
    var count = items?.Count () ?? 0;
    
    if (count == 0) return memAlloc (bytesAllocated);

    var sz = Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (T));
    bytesAllocated += sz * count;
    
    var result = memAlloc (bytesAllocated);
    result.Write (items, prefixBytes, bytesAllocated);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm maybe this will help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632646/marshall-array-of-structures

Comment: Thanks apocalypse! But in this example public Result[] Results; is an array, but in my case placeholderArray is a pointer to array

Comment: Hmm... maybe your `MarshalToPtr` method only allocates memory for struct itself, but does not allocate memory for child objects. When you marshaling that struct back from ptr, it tries to search in memory for chiud objects (which are not allocated).

Comment: Can you please give any suggestion how to fix it ?

Comment: But maybe I am wrong, there is a second extension method: `result.Write`. Maybe this method create child objects?

Comment: Well, when I am trying to marshall from IntPtr to Struct array it works fine.
function of converting intptr to struct array is below:


`public static void MarshalUnmananagedArray2Struct<T>(IntPtr unmanagedArray, int length, out T[] mangagedArray)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    mangagedArray = new T[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ins = new IntPtr(unmanagedArray.ToInt64() + i * size);
        mangagedArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(ins);
    }
 }`