# how to marshal to an Array of objects - C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am kind of confused by Marshal and C#.    I don't understand how to make a code change to marshal to an Array of Class.  This is what my current code looks like.

```
IntPtr pBarcodesRaw = IntPtr.Zero;
retVal = LeadTools13Imports.L_BarCodeRead( handle, null, // null to scan whole image                                                 (uint)barcodeTypes,
                         LeadTools13Imports.BARCODE_SCANLINES_PER_PIXELS,LeadTools13Imports.BARCODE_MARKERS,                                                                        1, //this parameter control if read the first bar code or all the bar codes.   0= first and 1 =                            all.
_barcodeReaderParams,IntPtr.Zero,
null,
out pBarcodesRaw );
```

Lead tools is a third party library.

This use to only read the first bar code and stop which was marshalling to a single instance of BarCodeData.    Now I have to read all the bar codes on a page.

```
if LeadTools13Imports.SUCCESS == retVal )
{  // extract the barcode read
    barcodeData = (LeadTools13Imports.BARCODEDATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure( 
                        pBarcodesRaw,
                        typeof( LeadTools13Imports.BARCODEDATA ) 
    );
}
```

The bar code data class looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class BARCODEDATA
{
    internal Int32  nGroup = 0; // used only for CodeOne and PDF417

    internal UInt32 ulType = 0;

    internal Int32  nUnits = 0;

    internal RECT   rcBarLocation = new RECT();
    
    internal Int32  nSizeofBarCodeData = 0;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]
    internal String pszBarCodeData = "";

    internal Int32  nIndexDuplicate = 0; // for reading only

    internal Int32  nTotalCount = 0; // for reading only

    internal Int32  nDupCount = 0; // for reading only
}
```

I added this class

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class BarCodeArray
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray , ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct , SizeConst = 2)]

    public BARCODEDATA[] _barcodes;
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding how do i change this line of code

```
barcodeData = (LeadTools13Imports.BARCODEDATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure( 
    pBarcodesRaw,
    typeof( LeadTools13Imports.BARCODEDATA ) );
```

to marshal to an array of `BARCODEDATA[]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marshall array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632646/marshall-array-of-structures)

Comment: @JeffRSon That is the solution I based my class on.    So, if I am reading that correct I should simply need to design my class but I got lost on how to Marshal it.  Let me keep trying.

Comment: If you look back at that solution, you will see that the key change was that he was using `struct`s and not `class`es

Comment: @TJRockefeller I am going to channel my inner Home Simpson and just say doooooooooh

Comment: So, I changed my class to a struct.    However I am now getting "The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack"

Comment: That is an access violation exception. When marshalling, the native data you are marshalling into C# has to be the *exact* same size as the struct that you are marshalling into. If you try to read in too many bytes you will cause access violation exceptions because you are trying to access memory you shouldn't have access to.

Comment: looking back at your classes, you never specify the size of `_barcodes`, you have to specify how that array needs to be marshalled with something like this `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 4)]` which I copied from the other answer.

Comment: I cannot see where you are using this new struct BarCodeArray - you should simply use it in Marshal.PtrToStructure.